# How to exit insert mode if pressing escape merely types "^["?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, escape

I have neovim 0.4.2 running in a session of kiTTY 0.17.4 on OSX. I have pasted a long url while in insert mode.

After doing this, every time I type <kbd>BKSPC</kbd> vim adds `^?` to my document. Every time I type <kbd>ESC</kbd> vim adds `^[` to my document. Because I cannot type <kbd>ESC</kbd> I cannot save or exit the document.

How do I get vim to exit insert mode?

```
~> nvim -v
NVIM v0.4.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/tmp/neovim-20191107-13403-1or2rj3/neovim-0.4.3/build/config -I/tmp/neovim-20191107-13403-1or2rj3/neovim-0.4.3/src -I/usr/local/include -I/tmp/neovim-20191107-13403-1or2rj3/neovim-0.4.3/deps-build/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim-20191107-13403-1or2rj3/neovim-0.4.3/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim-20191107-13403-1or2rj3/neovim-0.4.3/build/include
Compiled by brew@Mojave.local

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.4.3/share/nvim"
```

[image: Vim Session]

Comment: did you paste something? Looks like you are stuck in bracketed paste mode. Don't know of a way out, except for killing it (perhaps entering the bracketed paste end sequence helps)

Comment: Yes, I did indeed paste a long URL.

Answer (score 0):

> How to exit insert mode if pressing escape merely types "^["?

I am working on mintty on Windows with WSL and neovim. I can reproduce the "bracketed paste mode" (or what I started calling "caret mode") after pasing multiline text from a website using middle mouse button into neovim in INSERT mode. This is also reprodible with `nvim -u NONE`, but not that often.

I found out, that pasting the text *again* makes it "unstuck" from "bracketed paste mode". Try pasting the text again as you did and then typing exit.

Answer (score 0):

For Lua, you can use the following:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "jk", "<Esc>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

For Vimscript:

```
inoremap jk <Esc>
```

The code goes in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` or `.lua`.

Comment: This provides a mapping, but no default way. If you’re already stuck in insert mode, it’s too late to try to add a new mapping to trigger esc.