# Key Registration Problem

Tags: neovim, macos, iterm2

I have a problem that sometimes happens when I do type in Neovim. It does not register keys or mouse clicks correctly, which causes me to restart the iTerm session and rescue the working file with .swp.

Sorry for the not so clear explanation, but I have no idea how to describe it! Though, I have recorded a video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be0BzIRafd4

Why is this happening? Am I pressing some key combination I am not aware that cause this?

Nvim Dotfiles: https://github.com/ogirginc/dotfiles/tree/master/nvim

Comment: Interesting issue. Also intriguing that your Vim command line flickers with `...` on every keystroke. And how Esc or Ctrl+C or Ctrl+O don't work either... Do you have any suspicious plug-ins loaded? I wonder if this will also happen under `nvim --clean`, but since you're not sure of how to reproduce it, perhaps hard to tell... There's also `nvim -w scriptout` to log your keystrokes into a `scriptout` file, perhaps you could use that so you can inspect it later to see what happened just before the problem started?

Comment: Any mappings of esc?

Comment: @Ben the odd part is that the other typical ways of leaving normal mode (`<C-C>` or `<C-O>` for a one-off) aren't working either... I think I've seen a similar question recently, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26816/71 and https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26418/71 I believe you are still in bracketed-paste-mode. Most likely this is a bug of neovim.